# switch between colors in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem
first this is my code

```js
    $('.boxColor ul li').click(function () {
        $("link[href*='default']").attr('href', $(this).attr("data-color"));
    });
```

```html
    <section class="boxColor">
        <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <ul>
            <li data-color='css/color/alizarin.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/amethyst.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/concrete.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/nephritis.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/orange.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/piteRiver.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/pumpkin.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/wetAsphalt.css'></li>
            <li data-color='css/color/default_style.css'></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

the problem is when i click in the li to change the color,
the color changes just on the first click and when i click at another color is not work
the button of switch work just one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't include the `<link>` element in the HTML, but this is probably because after the first change, `link[href*='default']` will no longer select any elements because the new `href` doesn't contain the string `default`.

I recommend giving the link element in question an ID so that it remains the same all the time:

### HTML

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/color/default_style.css' id='color_stylesheet'>

<!-- other stuff follows -->
```

### JavaScript

```
$('.boxColor ul li').click(function () {
    $('#color_stylesheet').prop('href', $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```